# Query multiple keys in Redis in Cluster mode

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I'm using Redis in Cluster mode(6 nodes, 3 masters, and 3 slaves) and I'm using SE.Redis, However, commands with multiple keys in different hash slots are not supported as usual

so I'm using HashTags to be sure that certain key belongs to a particular hash slot using the `{}`. for example I have 2 keys like `cacheItem:{1}`, `cacheItem:{94770}`

I set those keys using ( each key in a separate request):

```
SEclient.Database.StringSet(key,value)
```

this works fine,

but now I want to query key1 and key2 which belongs to multiple hash slot

```
SEclient.Database.StringGet(redisKeys);
```

above will fail and throws an exception because those keys belong to multiple hash slots

while querying keys, I can't make sure that my keys will belong to the same hash slot, 
this example is just 2 keys I have hundreds of keys which I want to query.

so I have following questions:

how can I query multiple keys when they belong to different hash slots?
what's the best practice to do that?

should I calculate hash slots on my side and then send individual requests per hash slot?

can I use TwemProxy for my scenario?

any helps highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I can’t speak to SE.Redis, but you are on the right track. You either need to:

- Make individual requests per key to ensure they go to the right cluster node, or...
- Precalculate the shard + server each key belongs to, grouping by the host. Then send MGET requests with those keys to each host that owns them

Precalculating will require you (or your client) to know the cluster topology (hash slot owners) and the Redis key hashing method (don’t worry, it is simple and well documented) up front.

- You can query cluster info from Redis to get owned slots.
- The basic hashing algorithm is `HASH_SLOT=CRC16 (key) mod 16384`. Search around and you can find code for that for about any language  Remember that the use of hash tags makes this more complicated! See also: https://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot

Some Redis cluster clients will do this for you with internal magic (e.g. Lettuce in Java), but they are not all created equal

Also be aware that cluster topology can change at basically any time, and the above work is complicated. To be durable you’ll want to have retries if you get cross slot errors. Or you can just make many requests for single keys as it is much much simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Group by hash slot:

```
var keyList = keys.GroupBy(k => _redisConnection.GetHashSlot(k));
```

Then process each keyGroup with your favourite bulk command:

```
foreach (var keyGroup in keyList)
{
```